# Any help, stuck with my code when parsing a JSON from HTML. Needs to tell me when stock is True

Tags: python, json, if-statement, beautifulsoup

I have this JSON output in a HTML and I want to check the stock. I build everything already but I am stuck at the part when Python needs to tell me if the stock is true or not.

All the numbers are stores around the Netherlands. I just want to code that Python prints ''In Stock'' if only ONE of them is TRUE. I did the '' if ... or ... == 'True', but then if one of the stores is False, it's telling me it's still out of stock.

Any idea what kind of code I need to use to let Python tell me if one of the stores has stock?

I am using BS4, Beautifulsoup to parse the JSON.

Just stuck at the ''If... == 'True' part.

Thanks!

```
{"1665134":{"642":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"1298":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"1299":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"1322":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"1325":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"1966":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"1208":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"193":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"194":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"1102":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"1360":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"852":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"853":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"854":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"1239":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"855":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"856":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"857":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"858":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"859":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"860":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"861":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"1246":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"862":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"863":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"864":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"865":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"866":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"867":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"484":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"1380":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"868":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"869":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"1381":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"870":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"1255":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"871":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"360":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"872":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"873":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"746":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"875":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"876":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"749":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"1391":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"880":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"499":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"1275":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"1149":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false},"637":{"hasStock":false,"hasShowModel":false,"lowStock":false}}}
```

Python code;

```
def monitor():
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        voorraad = response.json()
        v1 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['193']['hasStock'])
        v2 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['194']['hasStock'])
        v3 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['360']['hasStock'])
        v4 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['484']['hasStock'])
        v5 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['499']['hasStock'])
        v6 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['637']['hasStock'])
        v7 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['642']['hasStock'])
        v8 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['746']['hasStock'])
        v9 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['749']['hasStock'])
        v10 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['852']['hasStock'])
        v11 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['853']['hasStock'])
        v12 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['854']['hasStock'])
        v13 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['855']['hasStock'])
        v14 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['856']['hasStock'])
        v15 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['857']['hasStock'])
        v16 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['858']['hasStock'])
        v17 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['859']['hasStock'])
        v18 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['860']['hasStock'])
        v19 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['861']['hasStock'])
        v20 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['862']['hasStock'])
        v21 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['863']['hasStock'])
        v22 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['864']['hasStock'])
        v23 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['865']['hasStock'])
        v24 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['866']['hasStock'])
        v25 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['867']['hasStock'])
        v26 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['868']['hasStock'])
        v27 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['869']['hasStock'])
        v28 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['870']['hasStock'])
        v29 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['871']['hasStock'])
        v30 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['872']['hasStock'])
        v31 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['873']['hasStock'])
        v32 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['875']['hasStock'])
        v33 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['876']['hasStock'])
        v34 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['880']['hasStock'])
        v35 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['1102']['hasStock'])
        v36 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['1149']['hasStock'])
        v37 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['1208']['hasStock'])
        v38 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['1239']['hasStock'])
        v39 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['1246']['hasStock'])
        v40 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['1255']['hasStock'])
        v41 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['1275']['hasStock'])
        v42 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['1298']['hasStock'])
        v43 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['1299']['hasStock'])
        v44 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['1322']['hasStock'])
        v45 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['1325']['hasStock'])
        v46 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['1360']['hasStock'])
        v47 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['1380']['hasStock'])
        v48 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['1381']['hasStock'])
        v49 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['1391']['hasStock'])
        v50 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['1966']['hasStock'])

        if any(v1, v2, v3):
            print(colored('[{}] ' + 'IN STOCK | ' + (product_title), 'green').format(str(datetime.now())))
            send_to_discord(product_title, webpagina, footerlogo, url, image_url)
            time.sleep(50)
            exit()
        else:
            print(colored('[{}] ' + 'OUT OF STOCK | ' + (product_title), 'red').format(str(datetime.now())))
            time.sleep(2)
```

Any was a test, not familiar with it...

Comment: I already used "v1 = (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)]['193']['hasStock'])" on every store number. 
Using ' If v1 == 'True' ', but I need to do that for all stores. If I use 'OR' it goes wrong. I need to have a sort 'if any of these are True...' .

Comment: Please give your python code so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

First, never write 50 variables manually when you can replace that with a loop...

assuming you need some specific ids, do the following:

`ids = ['193','192','360'...]` and loop over the array.

You said " just want to code that Python prints ''In Stock'' if only ONE of them is TRUE."  So only one, if the value is true for more than 1 store, you want the program to return false (logically you need at least one, not only 1, but I'm just following what you said). Also, judging by the code you already wrote, you don't seem to care which specific store has the stock.

In this case, this should work for you:

```
ids = ['193','192','360'...]
occurancesOfTrue=0;
for i in ids:
   if (voorraad['{}'.format(productid)][i]['hasStock']): occurancesOfTrue++;

if occurancesOfTrue==1:
    print(colored('[{}] ' + 'IN STOCK | ' + (product_title), 'green').format(str(datetime.now())))
    send_to_discord(product_title, webpagina, footerlogo, url, image_url)
    time.sleep(50)
    exit()
else:
    print(colored('[{}] ' + 'OUT OF STOCK | ' + (product_title), 'red').format(str(datetime.now())))
    time.sleep(2)
```

if you need it to be at least 1 occurrence, instead of 1 unique, replace   `if occurancesOfTrue==1:` by   `if occurancesOfTrue>=1:`

Comment: Thanks! I mean, if from all the ids one of them is true, just print in stock. I had the problem that a few were true and then one id was false and the system printed out 'out of stock'

Answer (score 0):

Your code will get way out of hand if you have that many manual entries that each do the same thing. First, I'd suggest making a list of product codes

```
products = [193, 194, 360, 384, ...]
```

the response.json() from js isn't what you'd use in python. first import

```
import json
```

then use json.loads() or json.dumps() to 'parse' and 'stringify' respectively

```
store = json.loads(<soup.whatever>)
```

and then I assume "1665134" is a merch id or something, which you can just iterate through subsequent objects

```
for product in store:
    if(product['hasStock']):
        # do stuff with stock
    else:
        # has no stock, you're sol
```

Comment: It's a website: https://www.mediamarktlabs.nl/api/realtime/?product=1665134
that's why I use reponse.json()

Comment: lol sorry. I shouldn't be smoking and getting on so